# Using the Stanford Named Entity Tagger in R

Tags: r, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am experimenting with the Stanford Named Entity Tagger  here http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/ner/process and I feel it would be useful in my research. Does anyone know of a example that I could follow so that I could do the analysis in R? Ideally I'd want to provide a string and get back a count (as a list) of the number of organisations, persons, etc recognised in the string. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/statsmaths/coreNLP  can be used as a wrapper for this library in R. Documentation has good examples for most use cases lie NER and POS.